SignalIntegrity cannot import name 'math' from 'numpy'
I can not launch the SignalIntegrityApp GUI application
I carefully followed the instructions in the website:https://github.com/Nubis-Communications/SignalIntegrity/wiki/Installation
However, when I type SignalIntegrity in the directory of the signalintegrity I get:
ImportError: cannot import name 'math' from 'numpy'
I even added the location of my SignalIntegrity project to the PYTHONPATH environment variable
As a result I can not launch the SignalIntegrityApp GUI application

I have seen this happen if I accidentally name my files with the name of a module, for example did you create a file named numpy.py?

@Nesi I don't think this is it: there really is no identifier named math in numpy

This is a version error.
In several files (eg SignalIntegrity/SignalIntegrity/Lib/Devices/SeriesC.py), SignalIntegrity calls
from numpy import math

except that module doesn't exist anymore. It was removed.
You should install an older version of numpy, eg.
pip install numpy=1.13

